# In SBT how can you write code that executes on initialization

Tags: scala, sbt

In a project build with `sbt`, if I want to extract a zip file every time the build is loaded / initialised, where should I add this code? I don't want to tie this to a `task` that needs to be invoked manually. Preferably when you are in the project folder and start the `sbt` shell I want this to happen. I found this, not sure it's fitting: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Build-Loaders.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this line in your build.sbt file :

```
val unzip = "unzip myZipToExtract.zip" !
```